# I am facing an error 'data' is undefined when trying to access the function parameter as mentioned in the comment in below code

Tags: javascript, html, css, flask

```
function categoryDetails(catId, code, label) {
  alert('Inside Categories Detail')
  $.post("/product/categories", {
    catId: catId,
    code: code,
    label: label,
    sess: socket.id
  }).done(function(data) {
    alert("Inside product capacity" + data.result)
    console.log(data.result)
    //In the below line I am trying to access the data parameter of the function but it says undefined
    var botHtml = '<div class="nn-bot-bubble"><div class="nn-bot-chips">{% for i in data.result %}<button id="sel_btn" value="{{ i.label }}"> {{ i.label }} </button>{% endfor %}</div></div>'
    $(".chat_block").append(botHtml);
  });
```

Here the `data` parameter is a dictionary with the key named 'result' and value a 'list'.
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: `bind()` is deprecated, you should use `on()`.

Comment: When you append the HTML to the DOM, Flask executes it in the global scope, not the scope of the function.

Comment: how do I append it using my function scope is there a solution ?

Comment: I don't know Flask, but I think you would use a loop in the JavaScript, not append HTML containing the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            function categoryDetails(catId,code,label){
            alert('Inside Categories Detail')
            $.post("/product/categories", {catId: catId,code:code,label:label, sess: socket.id}).done(function(data) {
                var text='';
                var middle='';
                var result='';
                capacitylist=data.result
                var start= '<div class="nn-bot-bubble"><div class="nn-bot-chips"><div class="button_block">'
                for (i = 0; i < capacitylist.length; i++){
                    text = capacitylist[i]['label'];
                    result='<button id="sel_btn" value="'+text+'">'+text+'</button>'
                    middle+=result
                }
                end='</div></div></div>'
                botHtml=start+result+end
                $(".chat_block").append(botHtml);
            });

        }
```

So here instead of running a loop inside the DOM, I used a javascript loop and then combined it.